Container for Swing properties
I'm not comfortable typing Swing property strings manually as it's error-prone (e.g. I can type "visibel" instead of "visible"). However, I haven't found any container for those property string constants OOB. Do I have to define some non-instantiable class with publiс static final strings like "visible" (as Swing has a ton of properties, it would be time-consuming)? Or maybe such a container was already written, wasn't it (by a third party, perhaps)? It seems quite likely
public class SwingProperties {
    // private constructor
    public static final String VISIBLE = "visible";
    // other properties
}

